# Excel - automatic name space creation for each column added in table

Tags: microsoft-excel

can i ask a question, is it possible to dynamically create namespaces  when excel table table grows horizontally .for example, i have 2 columns in my table (product,label), each column got its namespace to use in dropdownlist: product(product1,product2) and label(label1,label2), my table updates from source which can resize the table, for example adding a third coloumn called color(blue,red), the name space isn't created automatically for the new column in the table, is it possible to do it automagically?, thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "namespace" in an Excel table? Can you add a picture to your post to show what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

[image: vrf to bd][image: vrfs namespaces f]
[image: datavalidation] [image: dropdownlist]

as you can see, my vrf to bd table can at any time grow with new columns for which no namespace is yet created as a result the vrf drop downlist doesnt display the new vrfs in drop downlist,thus my question if a workaround around exist to automatically
redefine the new namespaces for the new columns?
Thanks